# How to remove :last-child border in Responsive page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a web page where inside a div I have 5 sub divs . To separate these divs I have given last child border

```
.col-lg-2:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #9a6eb7;
}
```

I want to remove these border to width 768px but I am not able to do this. If I use

```
.col-sm-6:not(:last-child) {
border-right: 0px solid #9a6eb7;
}
```

Then it is removing border for large width devices.

```css
.content
{
 clear:both;
 min-height:500px; 
}
.contentHeader
{
 font-size:40px;
 font-family:TROUPE-REGULAR;
 text-align:center;
 height:150px;
}

.content1
{
 float:left;
}
.content1 ,.content2 , .content3 , .content4 ,.content5
{
 height:313px;
}
h2 , p
{
text-align:center;
font-family:TROUPE-REGULAR; 
}

 .dog ,.cat,.bird
{
min-width:190px;
height:150px;
vertical-align:center;
}
.bunny , .hamster
{
 width: 180px;
    height: 106px;
 vertical-align:center;

}
.content .col-lg-2:not(:last-child) {
 border-right: 1px solid #9a6eb7;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 content">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  contentHeader">
WHY CHOOSE PetsApp
</div> <!-- end of contentHeader-->
<div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 Blank"> </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2 content1">
<h2> Lost & Found </h2> </br>
<p> simplified and effective
plateform to search and 
reunitelost pets with their
family
</p>
<img src="images/bunny.png" class="img-responsive bunny" alt="Bunny Image"/>
</div> <!-- end of content1 -->

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2 content2">
<img src="images/dog.png" class="img-responsive dog" alt="Dog Image"/>
<h2> Play Date</h2> </br>
<p> Connet with similar 
pets in  and around your
area. so your buddy will
never be alone.
</p> 
</div> <!-- end of content2 -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2 content3">
<h2> Adoption</h2> </br>
<p> Add or browse through our
lists of pets for adoption as
so them are in
need of a home
</p>
<img src="images/cat.png" class="img-responsive cat" alt="Adoption"/>
</div> <!-- end of content3 -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2 content4">
<img src="images/hamster.png" class="img-responsive cat" alt="Pet Book"/>
<h2> PET BOOK</h2> </br>
<p> What's your pet upto today?
Let the world know
</p>
</div> <!-- end of content4 -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2 content5">
<h2> INFO/ ARTICLES</h2> </br>
<p> Get Interesting tips and news
stories on everything you need to know about
pet health,behaviour and nutrition.
</p>
<img src="images/bird.png" class="img-responsive bird" alt="Info & Articles"/> </br>
</div> <!-- end of content5 -->

</div> <!--end of content-->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a specific style for screen with max-width of 768px you can use:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .col-sm-6:not(:last-child) {
        border-right: 0px solid #9a6eb7;
    }
}
```

This will be applied only if the max-width of your current device is 768px (larger screen will ignore this).

Comment: Provide a working example, otherwise it is very hard to understand what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Your code is not a working example. Put a jsfiddle or codepen that demonstrate exactly the problem.